# How to print files from folder > subfolder with powershell

Tags: algorithm, powershell, pdf, printing

I need to print more than 100 files that are in folder like that :

- Folder 1

  - Folder 1.1

    - File 1
    - File 2
    - Folder 1.1.1

      - File 10
  - Folder 1.2

    - File 3
    - File 4
    - File 5
    - etc...
- Folder 2

  - Folder 2.1
    etc...

I actually try to do this with powershell with an algorithm that will look at in every folder and print each files in each folder.

Can someone help me with that ?
Thanks you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the cmdlet `Start-Proccess` with the parameter `-Verb print`. This one line of code should do the job. This will print every file in the given folder on the default printer.

```
Get-Childitem "path\to\folder" -Recurse | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | %{ Start-Process -FilePath $_.Fullname -Verb print}
```

Please test it and let me know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks, it actually worked ! Did you have an idea how can I stop it ? Thanks !

Comment: I actually didn't think of that. I think you can stop the script with CTRL+C. But if the data is already on the printer, you might have to stop the print on the printer itself or clean the printer queue on your computer